# URL Acquisition Messaging

Tags: messages, changes

I work for an online retailer, and my company is acquiring the URLs from another online retail. We don't have plans to retain the acquired brands identity. We will simply be redirecting traffic to our site. I foresee this creating quite a stir for the faith users of this site.

My questions has two parts. First, are there any graceful examples of companies making this kind of move? Second, Do you have any thoughts about messaging? How and where is the right place to address the change?

I am still in the discovery phase, so I any ideas would help. I am pretty sure the company we are acquiring will give us access to their email lists, so we will be able to make some  preliminary introductions before the change.

Comment: +1 for your consideration of your customer experience. So many companies would do this without must (any?) thought as to the customer experience.

Answer (score 1):

The on-site part:

Perform the redirect, then based on the http referrer, decide to show a message. I'd go for something simple, but it depends on the amount of direct vs search traffic the acquired site had. If it is almost only search traffic, you could place a message, something like:

`Looking for acquiredSite.com? Read more.`

If traffic is much more direct, you might even go as far a a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my opinion to do it, is to redirect them to the identical page they wanted to go to, but on your site (if possible). Then at the top, maybe have a little dismissible notice that informs them about the acquisition, and has a link to read more about it.

Alternatively, you could redirect all traffic from that site to one page on your site explaining it, but I imagine that wouldn't earn you much additional revenue if they need to then search your site for the item.

If you sell the same items, redirect from the old sites items directly to yours, as per my first opinion.